# Taking Database backup: How to skip '/' from getdate so that it is not considered to be in a folder

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, database-backups

I am trying to take database backup. How can I do that when getdate is being appended with file name with format dd/mm/yyyy.

```
declare @dbName VARCHAR(100)
declare @path VARCHAR(100)
set @dbName='CallMeIndia'
set @path='F:\'+@dbName +'-'+convert(varchar(50),getdate(),103)+'.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE @dbName
TO DISK= @path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shantanu, a file can't include the `/` char in the name , try using another format, something like yyyymmdd (112) , you can check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for more formats.

```
set @path='F:\'+@dbName +'-'+convert(varchar(50),getdate(),112)+'.bak'
```